# Why is the Node.js Event Loop so slow on idle?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Maybe I've understood something wrong about the Event Loop, but it seems like 1000 rounds through the Event Loop take more than 1000ms.

```js
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

let counter = 0;
const timestamp_start = performance.now();

increment();
function increment() {
    if (counter === 1000) {
        console.log(`${Math.round(performance.now() - timestamp_start)}ms`); // -> 1186ms
    }
    else {
        counter++;
        setTimeout(increment, 0);
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior? What does the node process do all the time? xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing here is that you are relying on `setTimeout(fn,0)` to fire as soon as possible. It isn't the case, well, it wasn't always the case at least.

In both chromium and [node](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/eadef3f685cd9e96e94fcb9645b6838b6d0907a8/third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/dom_timer.cc#L79) there used to be a 1ms minimum timeout, apparently it's in the process of being removed in chromium (https://crbug.com/402694), but I believe even the latest nodejs still has it.

A better way to hook to the event-loop without delay is to use the `setImmediate` method, and there you'll see your full loop takes about 20ms.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5BTsMwELznFXtAqqOS1LkgJCvce@gbWsvZUEPsDfYGDlHeHuIAUYE5rLQ7szPzot91NMH2XHhqcJ4N@cgwQo@hpeC0NwgT1BDwbbABxS4R5yvRa9zlKss6ZDA0eMawqKTKvgzYOoysXX9eZuCFujEsPX2I9Gy9CejQc9rawRu25OHmCmMGC2wLYgupa6iklD9cQsqkDsuOnsXlbjxpvpZh0TfiXyoUf7vlk4uXXMHhAMUTVNXjg4ur87RO7CL@ilpr7PdqO0Xko3PYWM0otvL3IHP17TPN8yc)

Comment: Thaanks! You're great!  
I mistakenly thought that `setImmediate` is this fast because all callbacks are recursively added to the same Even Loop iteration (thus executed pseudo-synchronously and "starving" the Event Loop). But the Node.js docs clearly state: "If an immediate timer is queued from inside an executing callback, that timer will not be triggered until the next event loop iteration".

Comment: For anyone interested. With 'setImmediate' I now get >400K iterations per second on idle (instead of the wrong <1K iterations from my question) .